# Datetime formatting in Python does not match format

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a date stored in a string as:

```
date = '26 March 2018'
```

I'm trying to convert it to a datetime object with the following code:

```
date_element2 = datetime.strptime(date, '%d, %B, %Y')
```

But I'm getting the following traceback error:

```
ValueError: time data '26 March 2018' does not match format '%d, %B, %Y'
```

I can't figure out for the life of me how the formatting is incorrect, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Remove coma in your pattern

Comment: `'%d, %B, %Y'` should be like `'%d %B %Y'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove comma `,` from the format string, then it should work. For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = '26 March 2018'

#                              v  v  No comma here
>>> datetime.strptime(date, '%d %B %Y')
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 26, 0, 0)
```